# Input/output error using Python ADS1115, and a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, i2c, analog-to-digital

I am trying to read an analog signal using ADS1115 and a raspberry pi. Sometimes it reads and some time result into error.

Following is the code snippet

```
response = {}
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
t_trial = time.time()+2
GAIN = 1
while time.time() < t_end:
    try:
        test=adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN,data_rate=860)
        test=adc.read_adc(1, gain=GAIN,data_rate=860)
    except IOError as err:
        response['Error'] = True
        response['ErrorMessage'] = "ADC Failed to read"
        conn.send(json.dump(response))



L=[]
Lma = [] 
t_end = time.time() + 5
## Here I start the system(Using a relay) after which read is to be performed and it is to be done if and only if ADC read is possible.

while time.time() < t_end:

    L.append(adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN,data_rate=860))
    Lma.append(adc.read_adc(1, gain=GAIN,data_rate=860))
```

I have used try except to make sure ADC is working but this sometime works and sometimes result in following error.

```
File "XrayFBServer3.2.py", line 98, in threadServer
    L.append(adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN,data_rate=860))
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ADS1x15.py", line 192, in read_adc
    return self._read(channel + 0x04, gain, data_rate, ADS1x15_CONFIG_MODE_SINGLE)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ADS1x15.py", line 128, in _read
    self._device.writeList(ADS1x15_POINTER_CONFIG, [(config >> 8) & 0xFF, config & 0xFF])
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 129, in writeList
    self._bus.write_i2c_block_data(self._address, register, data)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 294, in write_i2c_block_data
    self._device.write(data)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I cannot reduce my data_rate. Shall I reduce my baud rate for I2con Raspberry Pi?

Question originally asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56789412/input-output-error-using-python-ads1115-and-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: AdaFruit's Python Library says its Rpi python library is deprecated.  So you might like to try their circuit python library instead. One other problem is that you cannot lower the fixed Rpi I2C baud rate, to hopefully make things more stable.  I did have the same instability problem (due to wires longer than 30 cm, too many I2C devices resulting pull down resistance to low (need to remove some of the pullups), total capacitance bigger than 400pF etc)  Perhaps you can upgrade stretch to buster to get more luck.  ( https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15/blob/master/README.md )

Comment: I2C I/O errors are usually due to loose or poor wiring.

Comment: @joan I tried and changed my jumper wires but the problem remains the same sometimes the output is fine but sometimes it results in the error